# update statement not working although code is right

Tags: vb.net

my update statement not working .. there is no effect on database when i check it

here is the code

conn.Open()

```
    Try
        Dim update As New OleDbCommand
    update.Connection = conn
        update.CommandText = " update O_name set fname = ' " & Name1.Text & " ' where ID = ' " & ID.Text & " ' "
        update.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("done")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
```

Comment: Your code is vulerable to SQL Injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: what is the column type of ID?

Comment: I think you should check Damith's post

Comment: it's text type in database and in vb

Comment: The way your query is written, it is expecting to find a space before and after the value in ID.Text.  For example is ID.Text has a value of "Hello", your where clause becomes:  `where ID = ' Hello '`  Notice the space before and after the word Hello.

Answer (score 2):

```
Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
Using command As New OleDbCommand("update O_name set fname =? where ID =?", connection)
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", Name1.Text)
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2",  ID.Text)
   command.Connection.Open()
   command.ExecuteNonQuery()
   MsgBox("done")
End Using 
End Using
```

use parameters but you need to specify parameters by using `?`, because :

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

**UPDATE:**

You have additional spaces in your parameter value assign, try below

```
update.CommandText = String.Format("UPDATE O_name SET fname ='{0}' WHERE ID ='{1}'",Name1.Text, ID.Text)
```

Comment: i need to know where is the error in the first code although i'm write tow codes (delete and Add) with the same method  i don't need new code just specify where is the error please

Comment: @user2780962 any exceptions? what is your database table definition? do you have record for given id in database?

Comment: i'm working on access , yes i have record , it says no value given for one ore more parameters

Comment: do you have column named `fname`? check the case also , it may be `Fname` or something else

Comment: yes i have and and the same "fname" please can you tell me what is the error in my code cause every thing happens correctly but no changes