# Why this error .. command text was not set to command object

Tags: vb.net, acc

conn.Open()

```
    Try
        Dim update As New OleDbCommand
        update.Connection = conn
        update.CommandText = " UPDATE O_name SET fname= '" & Name1.Text & "' WHERE ID = '" & ID.Text & "'"
        update.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("done")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try

    conn.Close()
```

there is always Error 
" Command Text was not set to command object " 
what's the reason 
please don't talk about parametrized query cause i'm asking about this specifically

Comment: _"please don't talk about parametrized query cause i'm asking about this specifically"_ You should use sql-parameters, it's not that difficult but helps to safe your database ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [update statement not working although code is right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811226/update-statement-not-working-although-code-is-right)

Comment: You can't really talk about parameterized queries enough! If you don't want us to talk about it, don't feed us by showing us a query that does things wrong.

Comment: i know it's protect me against sql injection but i want to know why this is error  it's make me crazy

Comment: give me parametrized and i'm sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

A quick google for the error message has a link [to this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2acf2fc8-4789-408a-b278-778236a2fff8/command-text-was-not-set-for-the-command-object) as the first search result, where someone writes:

> The problem was EvaluateAsExpression was not set to true..its working now..thanks again for the help :)

What kept you from using Google and finding it as quicky as I did?